# chdir to path defined by environment variable windows

Tags: python

I've a system evironment variable(on windows) defined as

```
MVN_ENV=C:\Users\mohitc\.mvn-env
```

I want to `chdir` to mvn-env directory defined by this environment variable.
On windows, I can either run the command or cd to: `%MVN_ENV%` to do so.

However, using `os.chdir("%MVN_ENV%")` throws:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '%MVN_ENV%'
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: `os.chdir(os.getenv('MVN_ENV'))`?

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't know that `"%MVN_ENV%"` is an environment variable, so it's just going to pass that literal string to `chdir()`, which can't do much with that. To get the actual environment variable you can find it in `os.environ['MVN_ENV']`, just pass that to `chdir` and you should be fine.